# It is necessary to find an error in the code

Tags: google-bigquery

In this code, you need to find an error and fix it, please help me, I just started learning sql and I'm still a beginner:

SELECT ID, NAME, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM date_import) AS YEAR
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE YEAR>= 2000

I can't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to select data from a table in a database, but there's a syntax error in your SQL query. The "SELECT" and "FROM" keywords should be in uppercase, and the "WHERE" clause should use the actual column name instead of the alias "YEAR". Here's the corrected query:

SELECT ID, NAME, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_import) AS import_year FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_import) >= 2000;
Copy
Also, make sure to replace "TABLE_NAME" with the actual name of your table.